# application role and Crystal Report 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I have my application created on VB.NET using SQL server 2008 R2. We have used crystal report for our data to view extensively. We have used connectionInfo interface class to build trusted and sometime non-trusted connection based on input to display data from SQL. We have newly implemented Database application role in our application to limit the access of user to the DB level. How can we implement Database application Role in case of Crystal Report while working with connectionInfo.

Thanks in advance looking forward to have positive response.

Regards,
Salman Momin

Answer (score 0):

See the first google response: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190998.aspx

You call/submit `sp_setapprole` with the application password from your VB.Net application.

Comment: @eLECTRIClIAMA Thanks for your response. I already gone through this link. I am using ConnectionInfo interface class for connecting my DB with Cyrstal reports with another user not one from which i have logged on. I wonder if i can get any solution where i can apply application role while creating connection with connectionInfo class.

Comment: Do you mean this ConnectionInfo class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226340(v=vs.80).aspx. It doesn't look like you can run any arbitrary SQL against that connection. Perhaps you could try just opening a standard ADO connection to the database and submit the `sp_setapprole` before you connect through ConnectionInfo

Comment: Yes Same ConnectionInfo Class. I assume that app roles required same connection if i will run app role with different connection and use DB with different connect will it works? I tried but it wont work few times back.  Please advice.  Thanks for your response.